# "System is running in low-graphics mode" error

Tags: unity, command-line, nvidia, graphics, fglrx

I am very new to working with Ubuntu and working with command line input. Last night I tried to install Netflix desktop app which required wine-compholio, wine-browser-installer and lib(I forget the rest of it). I noticed that when I was installing these, a lot of other programs were removed. After I installed the programs I tried to reboot my laptop. It wouldn't shutdown so I had to hard-shutdown. When turning it on again it gave me a "system is running in low-graphics mode" error. I have tried to solve the problem myself by researching it online but nothing has helped. I've tried using recovery mode, opening a terminal, trying to install nvidia and fglrx, but nothing has worked. Also, I keep getting the following warnings when trying to install anything in recovery mode terminal:
caution WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/sda5
caution WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab

I really need some help.

Thank you,
Edward

Answer (score 0):

The *low graphics mode* error can occur for a lot of reasons.

Please run these commands and post the output:

`$ cat /etc/fstab
$ df -h`

If you cannot access a terminal, open a `root` prompt via `GRUB`, or press or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> on your keyboard.

Also, you may try [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/nouveau) and see if it relates to your issue.